# How To Prevent App From Automatically Crashing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am using Android Studio and whenever I try to run my app it automatically crashes

Here is the `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.testing;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button residental;
    private Button highway;
    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int residentalAmount = 45;
        int highwayAmount = 75;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        highway = (Button) findViewById(R.id.highway);
        residental = (Button) findViewById(R.id.residental);

        highway.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answer.setText("You should go");
                //answer.setVisibility = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the `activity_main.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Click on One"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.126" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/residental"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am Driving on Residental Roads"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.714" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/highway"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am driving on the highway"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is what returns when I run the program

```
02/10 21:44:40: Launching 'app' on HMD Global N152DL.
Install successfully finished in 701 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 4685 on device 'hmd_global-n152dl-A00000V590272009041'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/example.testin: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:811): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.example.testing/code_cache/startup_agents/8dee6a62-agent.so" dev="dm-7" ino=10740 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c169,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c169,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.example.testing
V/studio.deploy: Startup agent attached to VM
V/studio.deploy: No existing instrumentation found. Loading instrumentation from instruments-b5380c1f.jar
W/example.testin: DexFile /data/data/com.example.testing/code_cache/.studio/instruments-b5380c1f.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
V/studio.deploy: ModifyParameterTransform failed: Landroid/app/ApplicationLoaders;
W/example.testin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
W/example.testin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
W/example.testin: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
W/example.testin: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
W/example.testin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
W/example.testin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
W/example.testin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.testing' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libMEOW: meow new tls: 0xb4000079f70c40b0
D/libMEOW: meow reload base cfg path: na
D/libMEOW: meow reload overlay cfg path: na
E/QT: [QT]file does not exist
D/libMEOW: applied 1 plugins for [com.example.testing]:
D/libMEOW:   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
D/libMEOW: meow delete tls: 0xb4000079f70c40b0
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testing, PID: 4685
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3587)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3834)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2249)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:209)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:296)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7882)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:181)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:804)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:922)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:889)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:691)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at com.example.testing.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:13)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3574)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3834) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:209) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:296) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7882) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045) 
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: Any `findViewById()` method should be called within the Activity's methods so you should move `TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);` to inside `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nullpointerexception because code is attempting findViewById (TextView answer) on a null view since setContentview has not been called;

Initialize Textview answer after setContentView() in onCreate just like the other views. setContentView() needs to be called first before findViewById() ;

```
    package com.example.testing;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button residental;
        private Button highway;
        TextView answer;
        @Override
    
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int residentalAmount = 45;
            int highwayAmount = 75;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            highway = (Button) findViewById(R.id.highway);
            residental = (Button) findViewById(R.id.residental);
            answer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    
            highway.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    answer.setText("You should go");
                    //answer.setVisibility = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```